# Clarification on header and footer with .html and .php

Tags: php, html, web, structure

I have been building a website in PHP. I am confused about the method or techniques to get the pages to display properly.

My main point of entry is `index.html`. From here, the user can click to navigate. I want all 12 pages to have the same header information.
I tried using  tags in Dreamweaver and then just  tags.

?? I am confused about the difference between using  tags and using
a file called `header.php`

**FOLLOW UP:** To suggested responses. I edited the code as suggested
Now when I 'view in browser' I get 'Server Not Found'.

Note. I am using DreamweaverCC:

Document Root /library/WebServer/Documents

**header.php**:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
     <h1>General Header Information for Top of Each Page</h1>
```

**index.html**

```
<?php include_once ('header2.php');  ?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>index.php</title>
<link href="file:////Library/WebServer/Documents/webDevelopDWsites        /boilerplate.css"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/webDevelopDWsites/indexFourSquare.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/webDevelopDWsites/respond.min.js">  </script>
</head>
<body>

<?php include 'header2.php';  ?>
    <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div id="div1" class="fluid">
    <header id="header" class="fluid">Web Development by myName</header>

    <div id="Square1" class="fluid"><a href="file:///Library/WebServer/Documents /webDevelopDWsitesimages/Square1.jpg"><img src="images/Square1.jpg"  alt=""/></a></div>

    <div id="Square2" class="fluid"><a href="file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/webDevelopDWsites/Square2.html"><img src="images/Square2.jpg"  alt=""/></a></div>

     <div id="Square3" class="fluid"><a href="file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/webDevelopDWsites/Square3.html"><img src="images/Square3.jpg"  alt=""/></a></div>

     <div id="Square4" class="fluid"><a href="file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/webDevelopDWsites/Square4.html"><img src="images/Square4.jpg"  alt=""/></a></div>

     <div id="siteMap" class="fluid">siteMap</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Do I include `header.php` in the code of each of these other pages? I did do this but it did not work.

So I have tried this: I created an `index.php` and copied all of the `index.html` code into `index.php` and also added this at the top of the code.

```
<?php include 'header.php';  ?>
```

When I use 'view in browser' launching `index.html`:

- I get the webpage correctly
- But 'no header information.'

When I click on the images to navigate to the other pages, it works:

- But 'no header information'.

When I click on `index.php`:

- I ONLY get the header information.

Comment: By default, you have to specify ".php"for your extension. Otherwise, your php code will not be interpreted.

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion What is the forbidden term in the edits? I changed the title so that your problem is easier to find and you may get more answers.

Comment: @icanhascheezburger Progress. 'Unable to connect' Document Root Library/WebServer/Documents. I created new folder: Library/WebServer/Documents/dwwdSite (=DreamWeaverWebDevelopmentSite). But when I type URL localhost/dwwdSite/ error: 'unable to connect'.  Site setup for dwwdSite: name = localhost. address = macHD/library/WebServer/Documents. connection= Local/Network. testing checked. Local info web URL: Http://localhost/. Site Name = dwwdSite. Local Site Folder = /Library/WebServer/Documents/dwwdSite. I feel like I must have something incorrect in these settings. Still 'unable to connect'.

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion Which server package are you using? wamp or xampp? In the default setting of wamp, the websites should be hosted in c:/wamp/www whereas for xampp it's c:/xampp/htdocs, if you have these directories created, you can place your website folder in one of them. Also, another important thing is, they should be started. For xampp look at the [8th point here](http://sawmac.com/xampp/) and for wamp [watch this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C84KTCTTaEg)

Comment: @icanhascheezburger I have mama installed.  After I modify setting for example<IfModule dir_module> DirectoryIndex index.php index.html </IfModule> I restart apache. I now have the error 'unable to connect which is posted in another thread. I am going to list the server settings and configurations shown in screen shots. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, a website is broken into 3 parts:

[image]

The header and footer follow all the pages, it's ONLY the between that changes. So on your **header.php**, you will have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>headerForFourSquares
</title>
</head>
<body>    
        <h1>General Header Information for Top of Each Page.</h1>
```

That's it, no closing the `<body>` tags here.

Now in your **index.php**, you would do:

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>

//all your index content here

<?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
```

And finally **footer.php**:

```
</body>
</html>
```

That's the way it works. For each of your other pages, you should be including the header and footer like above.

Your Index file **has** to be with `.php` extension. Header and footer file can be of **.html** extension if they have no PHP code.

> You say index.html is not going to execute any php code but you do not
>   explain why.

When you have PHP code in your `.html` file, When the browser is opening a `.html` file which contains PHP code, it's not expecting any PHP code to be present, and thus does not interpret it. Although, you can force it to interpret PHP following [here](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm) but this in itself is a bad practice as conflict may arise among other languages like `<?xml` since PHP also begins with `<?`.

And the reason why you need to run it through *localhost* and not by opening the file path through browser is because while HTML is a client-side script, it can run freely without any server but PHP is a server-side script and will be interpreted *only* by a server, that's why we use web server packages such as xampp, wamp etc. to test locally.

Comment: Note regarding `index.html`, many dynamic websites use their respective language extensions for the bootstrapping files.  However they disguise them as plain HTML files by rewriting the url (apache mod rewrite for example).  Thats why they dynamic despite appearing static html files.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. This comment box only allows for 500+ characters.  I want to include my code. How do I do this ????  I am getting a 'server not found error' when I launch index.php.  I do not get this when I launch(view in browser) index.html.

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion index.html is not going to execute ANY PHP code, so you can forget about it, as for the code, you can edit your question above and paste.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Thanks for the info.  I edited my original post. You say index.html is not going to execute any php code but you do not explain why.

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion I've added a portion explaining why it won't work, feel free to ask for more information. As for your edited code, you're doing it completely wrong, the code from your `<!doctype` till `<body>` need to be in a `header2.php`. Call it _only_ once at the top of `index.php` using `include_once()`. In case you're confused, `include_once()` will simply paste the contents of the file mentioned inside the `()`.

Comment: Woah. I just scanned you feedback.... Nice explanation. I have to work on it now.  Will update you.

Comment: Document Root library/WebServer/Documents